# Using Convert Style Option 2 for a large number of XML files at once in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, xpath, data-conversion

I am pretty new at this so please bear with me. I am attempting to transfer many XML files into Microsoft SQL Server in one go. Unfortunately I am getting an error saying I need to convert with style option 2. I do not know how to do this for so many files.

Here is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[staagingTable]
(
    [Counter] INT NOT NULL,
    [majority] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [congress] [int] NULL,
    [session] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [chamber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [rollcall-num] [int] NULL,
    [legis-num] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [vote-question] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [vote-type] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [vote-result] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [action-date] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [action-time] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [vote-desc] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [sourceXML] [XML] NULL
);
GO

DECLARE @Counter INT=1;
DECLARE @command VARCHAR(MAX);

WHILE @Counter<800
BEGIN
    SET @command=
    '
    DECLARE @xml XML=
    (
    SELECT BulkColumn
    FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ''C:\Users\Owner\Documents\congress\House votes\114 congress 2015\Passage\roll' + REPLACE(STR(@Counter,3),' ','0') + '.xml'', SINGLE_BLOB) AS c
    );

    INSERT INTO dbo.staagingTable(Counter, majority, congress,[session], chamber, [rollcall-num], [legis-num], [vote-question], [vote-type], [vote-result], [action-date], [action-time], [vote-desc], [sourceXML])
        SELECT 
            ' +  CAST(@Counter AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',
            v.value(N''majority[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''),
            v.value(N''congress[1]'', N''int''),
            v.value(N''session[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''),
            v.value(N''chamber[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''),
            v.value(N''rollcall-num[1]'', N''int''),
            v.value(N''legis-num[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''), 
            v.value(N''vote-question[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''),
            v.value(N''vote-type[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''),
            v.value(N''vote-result[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''),
            v.value(N''action-date[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''),
            v.value(N''action-time[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''),
            v.value(N''vote-desc[1]'', N''nvarchar(max)''),
            @xml
        FROM 
            @xml.nodes(N''/rollcall-vote/vote-metadata'') AS A(v);
    ';

    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC(@command);
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH;

    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
END

SELECT * FROM dbo.staagingTable;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.staagingTable;
```

What I need is some way to resolve this that will deal with all of the files at once. The errors saying that it cannot bulk load due to the file not existing is not an issue since those files actually don't exist. In the picture below the errors that do matter have a symbol drawn next to them in purple. These aren't the only ones though. There are hundreds of them. These are just some of the ones I scrolled to. The two types of error you see below are the only ones that the execution of my query yielded.

[image: the screenshot of my errors]

The files all contain identical columns, the same data types, but varying values for the columns. Below is baby version of one such xml document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE rollcall-vote PUBLIC "-//US Congress//DTDs/vote v1.0 20031119 //EN" "http://clerk.house.gov/evs/vote.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://clerk.house.gov/evs/vote.xsl"?>
<rollcall-vote>
    <vote-metadata>
         <majority>R</majority>
         <congress>114</congress>
         <session>1st</session>
         <chamber>U.S. House of Representatives</chamber>
         <rollcall-num>6</rollcall-num>
         <legis-num>H RES 5</legis-num>
         <vote-question>On Agreeing to the Resolution</vote-question>
         <vote-type>YEA-AND-NAY</vote-type>
         <vote-result>Passed</vote-result>
         <action-date>6-Jan-2015</action-date>
         <action-time time-etz="17:30">5:30 PM</action-time>
         <vote-desc>Adopting rules for the One Hundred Fourteenth Congress</vote-desc>
         <vote-totals>
             <totals-by-party-header>
                 <party-header>Party</party-header>
                 <yea-header>Yeas</yea-header>
                 <nay-header>Nays</nay-header>
                 <present-header>Answered â€œPresentâ€</present-header>
                 <not-voting-header>Not Voting</not-voting-header>
             </totals-by-party-header>
             <totals-by-party>
                 <party>Republican</party>
                 <yea-total>234</yea-total>
                 <nay-total>4</nay-total>
                 <present-total>1</present-total>
                 <not-voting-total>3</not-voting-total>
             </totals-by-party>
             <totals-by-party>
                 <party>Democratic</party>
                 <yea-total>0</yea-total>
                 <nay-total>168</nay-total>
                 <present-total>0</present-total>
                 <not-voting-total>5</not-voting-total>
             </totals-by-party>
             <totals-by-party>
                 <party>Independent</party>
                 <yea-total>0</yea-total>
                 <nay-total>0</nay-total>
                 <present-total>0</present-total>
                 <not-voting-total>0</not-voting-total>
             </totals-by-party>
             <totals-by-vote>
                  <total-stub>Totals</total-stub>
                  <yea-total>234</yea-total>
                  <nay-total>172</nay-total>
                  <present-total>1</present-total>
                  <not-voting-total>8</not-voting-total>
             </totals-by-vote>
         </vote-totals>
    </vote-metadata>
    <vote-data>
        <recorded-vote>
            <legislator name-id="A000374" sort-field="Abraham" unaccented-name="Abraham" party="R" state="LA" role="legislator">Abraham</legislator> 
            <vote>Yea</vote>
        </recorded-vote>
        <recorded-vote>
             <legislator name-id="A000370" sort-field="Adams" unaccented-name="Adams" party="D" state="NC" role="legislator">Adams</legislator>
             <vote>Nay</vote>
        </recorded-vote>
        <recorded-vote>
            <legislator name-id="A000055" sort-field="Aderholt" unaccented-name="Aderholt" party="R" state="AL" role="legislator">Aderholt</legislator>
            <vote>Yea</vote>
        </recorded-vote>
    </vote-data>
</rollcall-vote>
```

Comment: In my answer I use `DECLARE @xmlString NVARCHAR(MAX)`. If you get issues, try gthe same without the `N` (simple `VARCHAR(MAX)`). I got some trouble with the actual encoding of your file on disc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your reading part to this:

```
--DECLARE @xmlString NVARCHAR(MAX)= --try one of these...
DECLARE @xmlString VARCHAR(MAX)=
(
SELECT BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ''C:\StackOverflow\xml' + REPLACE(STR(@Counter,3),' ','0') + '.xml'', SINGLE_BLOB) AS c
);
SET @xmlString=SUBSTRING(@xmlString,CHARINDEX(''<rollcall-vote>'',@xmlString,1),9999999);

DECLARE @xml XML=CAST(@xmlString AS XML);
```

This will first read your file into a normal string variable, then cut off everything until `<rollcall-vote>`. This cleaned string can be casted to XML. The rest should work as before.

Comment: It worked! I have ended up with a single large table containing all the data. I wanted them to be in different tables and I wanted more columns to go with it but so far this is good! I will do my best to figure out the rest.

Comment: @anang Just one hint: A staging table is not the final target... It is meant the way you are doing this. Write everything in there, might be clever to add some more columns (e.g. `year`) and then transfer all data out of the staging table into your final target table(s).

Comment: I think I will do everything step by step. First I will attempt to figure out how extract all the other data values I want from a single one of my xml files and combine it with what I already have for that file via a crossjoin. Then I will try to apply that method to all the files at the same time. And then lastly I will attempt to transfer all data out of my staging table into my final target tables.